# Type-safe object composition

Tags: java, oop, generics, composition

I am currently working on a network health monitoring system that allows to watch multiple kind of resources, diagnose based on facts and react according to the diagnostic.

## Initial thoughs...

My initial thoughts was to have an abstract `Watcher` class, which can be configured with a `Diagnosis` object (which is responsible for producing a `Diagnostic` based on `Facts`) and a list of `DiagnosticHandler` objects. This `Watcher` class would have a `abstract protected Facts _check()` template method overridden by subclasses such as `HttpWatcher` or `MemoryWatcher`.

`Facts` is a marker interface and represents what can be observed to generate a `Diagnostic`. For example, the `_check` method of `HttpWatcher` would return `HttpFacts` which is basically the http response details.

Here's what the `HttpWatcher` constructor may look like:

```
public HttpWatcher(
    Duration interval, 
    Diagnosis<HttpFacts> diagnosis, 
    List<DiagnosticHandler> handlers,
    URL url
)
```

As we can see, since this class's `_check` method returns `HttpFacts`, it also only allows `Diagnosis` strategies that can diagnose based on `HttpFacts` and that is what we want. This way it is possible for the compiler to complain if an incompatible `Diagnosis` strategy is used.

## Missing concept?

However, there is something that bother's me with this design because I noticed that in terms of behavior, the only thing that `Watcher` subclasses overrides is the `_check` method. Even worse, the `_check` algorithm could not be reused somewhere else. This made me thinking that perhaps I was missing a `Resource` concept in my design that could encapsulate the algorithm to retrieve `Facts` rather than having to subclass `Watcher`.

This being said, I would only need a concrete `Watcher` class which would be configured with a `Resource`, a `Diagnosis<T extends Facts>` and a `List<DiagnosticHandler>`.

This design makes much more sense to me, but then I would lose the type-safety that prevents incompatible strategies to be used together like below:

```
new Watcher(
    new Duration(...),
    new HttpResource(...),
    new SimpleMemoryDiagnosis(...), /*<- incompatible with HttpResource*/
    ...
)
```

## Solution?

It's been a while since I programmed in a strongly-typed language and I want to make sure that I use the types to my advantage, but at the same time I do not want my design to suffer.

One idea that I had was to create a new class such as `HttpWatchedResource` which would encapsulate `HttpResource` and `Diagnosis<HttpFacts>` objects.

Something like:

```
public abstract class WatchedResource {
    private final Resource resource;
    private final Diagnosis diagnosis;

    public WatchedResource(Resource resource, Diagnosis diagnosis) {
        //null checks
        this.resource = resource;
        this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
    }

    //called by Watcher
    public final Diagnostic checkHealth() {
        return diagnosis.diagnose(resource.facts());
    }
}

public final class HttpWatchedResource {
    public HttpWatchedResource(HttpResource resource, Diagnosis<HttpFacts> diagnosis) {
        super(resource, diagnosis);
    }
}
```

The `Watcher` constructor would then look like:

```
public Watcher(
    Duration interval, 
    WatchedResource resource, 
    List<DiagnosticHandler> handlers,
    URL url
)
```

**I would like to know if there's a widely adopted pattern used when an object is composed of multiple strategies that could potentially be incompatible and/or if I'm heading in the right direction with the proposed solution?**

Comment: I suggest you pick a language, Java or C#.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well, this question is pretty much language agnostic. Any strongly typed OO languages based on the classical model would have a similar solution I believe. I only added the `C#` tag to draw more attention to the question.

Comment: C# doesn't have generics.  I suggest you make the design as simple as possible.

Comment: C# most definitely does have generics

Comment: @PeterLawrey I just had a look C# does support generics. However if you have an idea on a design that wouldn't need them feel free to post an answer.

Comment: With OO Design you can create something very elaborate and much more complicated than you need.  I suggest you as yourself; what is the simpler and clearest way to implement this? Only you know what you find simplest.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well in a dynamic untyped language like JS for instance the design could be much more simplistic, but at the same time there could easily be a runtime error just because incompatible strategies would be used together. I am trying to find a solution that allows me to use composition rather than inheritance, but without giving up the type safety that I had.

Comment: What would be wrong with `HttpWatchedResource implements WatchedResource<HttpFacts>` and `Diagnosis<HttpFacts>`? Even if an interface is parametric the concrete implementation doesn't need to be.

Comment: Peter, you might be interested in Wadler's paper [Theorems for Free](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=99370.99404), which demonstrates how e.g. generics greatly simplify code by constraining the domain (and codomain) of a function at the type level.

Comment: @monocell I am not sure if I understand what you are proposing. I added a few more details about the implementation I was thinking about. Perhaps you could expand a little more on how to achieve a similar result with the solution you propose? Thanks!

Comment: @monocell The main goal of all this is to make sure both `Resource` and `Diagnosis` works with the same type of `Facts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something, but based on my current understanding of the
problem I would do something like:

```
public class Watcher<T> {
    public Watcher(Resource<T> res, Diagnosis<T> diag) {
    ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public class HttpResource implements Resource<HttpFacts> {
   ...
}
```

That would guarantee that the Watcher and the Diagnosis are
always of compatible types, and still allow you to override
either.

I might very well be missing something crucial though.

Comment: Yeah I think this is it! Making the `Watcher` generic is far more interesting since I do not need this `WatchedResource` wrapping concept which was making the design more complex. Thanks!